# How do I stop bootstrap-sass gem from loading Bootstrap js twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

This is my Gemfile:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0.0'
```

This is my `application.js`:

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap.file-input
```

My `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss` looks like this:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

When I view the source of my page, I see this:

```
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/affix.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/alert.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/button.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/carousel.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/collapse.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/dropdown.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/tab.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/transition.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/scrollspy.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/modal.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/tooltip.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/popover.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap-sprockets.js?body=1"></script>
```

The official documentation says this:

```
Plugins can be included individually (using Bootstrap's individual *.js files), or all at once (using bootstrap.js or the minified bootstrap.min.js).
```

What is happening is whenever I use the default modal code from Bootstrap's site in my app, it fires quickly and disappears. After much research, I believe this is because Bootstrap is being loaded twice. The regular `Bootstrap.js` contains the info needed for the modal, so I don't need to include `bootstrap/modal.js`, but I am not sure how to remove it.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you include it twice, apparently. The [official docs](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) say:

> Require Bootstrap Javascripts in
>   `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`:
>
> ```
> //= require jquery
> //= require bootstrap-sprockets
> ```

Comment: So are you saying don't `require bootstrap`?